# Win7 load balancing over 2 default gateways and 1 interface

Tags: networking, router, routing, dhcp

This is a scenario I've been working on lately: My PC has 1 NIC connected to a 192.168.100.0/24 network. This network has 2 gateways to the Internet, namely .1 and .254. Now I want to get to the Internet through both of these gateways, for well, better speed of course (aka load balancing)

The first solution that I tried and did succeed is as follows: I make one of the two gateways as the DHCP server (say the .1). So my PC will receive the .1 as its default gateway through DHCP. Then I only need to add another default route through the other GW on my PC, with the same metric as the first one (ROUTE ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 192.168.100.254 METRIC 40). Now my routing table shows 2 default routes with the same metric, but going through 2 different GWs. I did some tests and the speed was indeed increased (to the sum of both Internet connections)

Now I want to push it a little further. I don't want to manually add that second default route on every host on my LAN. So I tried to have the DHCP server push 2 default routers in its DHCP allocation, instead of 1. I used DHCP option 3 (router) and specified 2 addresses of the 2 GWs (.1 and .254). My PC did take both those two addresses as its default GWs, but unfortunately with **different metrics**. I know this is because option 3 specifies "Available routers, should be listed in **order of preference**". Now I wonder if there is a way to negate this "order of preference"

So my question is how to overcome this and make the PC take 2 GWs with the same metric, so it can load balance on them

Any suggestion?